# Punishing the diligent niddah

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah

In general, [a *niddah* should not postpone immersion](http://www.yoatzot.org/article.php?id=166).

According to current universal custom, after observing a disqualifying stain, [a *niddah* must observe 7 clean days](http://www.yoatzot.org/article.php?id=53) before immersion, whereas [a *tehorah* must wait at least 5 days before observing 7 clean days](http://www.yoatzot.org/topic.php?id=40).

Consider these two scenarios:

1. Rochel finishes counting 7 clean days, and diligently immerses that night. The next morning she finds a disqualifying stain, and must wait at least 5 + 7 = 12 days in order to immerse again.
2. Leah finishes counting 7 clean days, and laxly postpones her immersion. The next morning she finds a disqualifying stain, and must wait only 7 days in order to immerse again.

Why is the diligent being punished?

Comment: Because sometimes, life isn't fair? // Is Leah required to keep doing bedikot and taking other measures that make finding such a stain more likely? In that case, it's quite possible that the same stain that would make Leah count another 7 days would be undetected by Rochel, so she'd wait 0 days.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Leah is NOT required to continue bedikos. See last line of first link: "If one has finished counting the shivah neki'im but is postponing immersion, it is no longer necessary to wear white underwear or do bedikot."

Comment: What causes a concern to wait 5 days is only relevant for a *Tehora*. It isn't a קנס.

Comment: Note that 5 days is not a universal custom. Plenty of non-Ashkenazim do not have that practice.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is news to me. Can you tell me what other practice there is out there? Less than 5 days? Some other criteria?

Comment: @NBZ 4 days is out there as is douching and just starting the next day, or only waiting if the couple had Biah recently.

Answer (score 7):

The diligent is not being punished.  The waiting 5 days is not a result of being *tehora* - it is a result of having cohabited with (or having been able to cohabit with) her husband, and therefore having a concern of discharging *shichvas zera*, which invalidates the counting of those days. The woman who went to *mikvah* has a concern of discharge, and the other woman does not.  It is not a result of being *tehorah*, even if it is a consequence.

Someone who consumed meat for their Yom Tov seudah cannot have a glass of milk, while someone who did not have meat can.  The one who consumed meat is not being punished for having made a nicer Yom Tov meal (assuming they both like meat) - he is merely subject to the consequences of having eaten meat, which is incidental to the *mitzvah* of *seudas Yom Tov*.  This is the same thing.

Comment: Note further that if a Niddah did sleep with her husband during the seven clean days she'd have to wait five days to resume her count.

Comment: @DoubleAA Really? What is the source for that?

Comment: @NBZ same source as the waiting 5 days before starting - poletes shichvas zera can't start counting because the Sh"Z is soseir yomo.  It will be soseir yomo in the middle just as well as at the beginning.

Comment: @DoubleAA Look at Shach on 196. He points out that even according to the Remo one would only wait 4 days in such a case seeing as it is a rare case the stringency of the Terumas Hadeshen (that maybe they had Biah Bein Hashmashos) was not said there